# End extension models of $I\Delta_0$

Tags: logic, model-theory, peano-axioms

Recently I'm thinking about below question, but I can not prove or disprove it.

> Is it true that for every model $M\models I\Delta_0$ there exists a model $M'\models PA$ such that $M'$ is end extension of $M$?

How can this statement prove or disprove?

Thanks.

Comment: Also asked at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/225169/end-extension-models-of-i-delta-0 .  Please do not ask the same question quickly on both sites - it is polite to wait for at least a week or two before moving to the other site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question in math overflow and thanks to [Joel David Hamkins](https://mathoverflow.net/users/1946/joel-david-hamkins)
now I know the answer.

By Incompleteness theorem $I\Delta_0 \nvdash Con(I\Delta_0)$, so there exists model like $M\models I\Delta_0+\neg Con(I\Delta_0)$. On the other hand $PA\vdash Con(I\Delta_0)$, so there is no model $M'\models PA$ such that $M'$ is end extension of $M$.

Comment: This answer should probably be marked as community wiki.